# $.post() callback method suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

I always used something like this:

```
$("a.button").click(function() {
    data = ...;
    url = ...;
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

The problem is when an user has a slow connection and clicks on that button, it doesn't seems to do anything, because the button will change the own status (adding the `active` class) once the request is complete. Of course I can "fix" this behavior by adding a spinner while the request is loading.

Now check out this one:

```
$("a.button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    data = ...;
    url = ...;
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        // if request is successful do nothing
        // else, if there's an error: $(this).toggleClass('active)
    });
});
```

In other words, I change the button status instantly when the button is pressed and after this, I check for success/error. Is this a good way? What you think about? Are there other ways?

Comment: It depends... Do you want your button to be set as active during the whole time of the Ajax request or just during the instant the user clicks it?

Comment: Yeah, based on your description it's a good way.

Comment: Also you cannot use $(this) inside $.post. You have to define it before: `var $t = $(this); $.post(....function(){ $t.toggleClass(..`

Comment: @Nabab: I'm asking for that. If I add the `active` class once the request is completed I need to add a loading spinner.

Comment: @Nabab: if, in your opinion, is better to change the status once the request is completed or just when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a UI question than code. Personally I prefer to show the spinner in cases where it could be confusing if there is no response. Since I don't know what class you're toggling and what effect it has on the element, I wouldn't know if toggling before success would be confusing at all.

One way or another, everyone alive knows the loading spinner. It's probably safe to go with that.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the general idea there. You can implement it in other ways, for instance by setting global AJAX `ajaxStart` and `ajaxSuccess` functions:

```
$("a.button").click(function() {
    data = ...;
    url = ...;
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        // if request is successful do nothing
    });
}).ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
}).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
}).ajaxError(function () {
    //never forget to add error handling, you can show the user a message or maybe try the AJAX request again
});
```

> These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such
>   as initialization or completion, take place for any AJAX request on
>   the page. The global events are fired on each AJAX request if the
>   global property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true, which it is by default.
>   Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP
>   requests, regardless of the value of global.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/*

Comment: If you're using `ajaxStart`, shouldn't you use `ajaxStop`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: `ajaxStop` runs when ALL ajax requests are done, where as `ajaxComplete` runs for each one.

Comment: @Rocket Right, but he's using `ajaxStart` which runs only once for overlapping requests.  So you will toggle once at the start and then potentially toggle multiple times on complete.  Unless I'm misunderstanding, this could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @JamesMontagne `ajaxStop` runs whenever the AJAX request is done, `ajaxComplete` runs for a successful AJAX response, and `ajaxError` runs for an un-successful AJAX response. so the bases are covered, I like to use `complete`/`error` so my error code is separate from my success code.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: You're right, `ajaxStart` only runs once, too.  `ajaxSend` runs for each request.

Comment: It runs only if another AJAX request is not currently being sent. Which is what you want for a loading spinner right? No need to replace a loading spinner with a loading spinner.

Comment: @Jasper consider 2 ajax requests overlapping, active class initially not present.    `ajaxStart` adds the class, then the first `ajaxComplete` removes it and then the 2nd `ajaxComplete` adds it back.  The final result is that `active` is set while no requests are outstanding.

Comment: Anyway, good points guys. If anyone chooses to use jQuery's Global AJAX events then my all means read the documentation for each one carefully and select the one(s) that make sense for what you're doing.

Comment: @JamesMontagne That's certainly a good point. I personally wouldn't use `toggleClass` and I would explicitly add or remove the class for the specific situation. I don't think I'm going to update my code unless the OP chimes in because I don't know what they're doing for sure. I'm fairly sure they used `toggleClass` because their code was pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Jasper: my code is pretty simple yes, but I prefer me too to use `addClass` and `removeClass` instead `toggleClass`. My question is: how you choose whether add or remove the class? You return some json like `add: true` or `add: false` and you check it?

Comment: @FredCollins The code you have posted does not use JSON, but if you want to use it then you can use `$.ajax({ dataType : 'json', type : 'post' })` to do a POST request that returns JSON (although your server-side script mush output valid JSON). Generally a loading spinner is shown when the AJAX request is on-going, so you hide it after the AJAX request completes, so show the spinner on `ajaxStart` and hide it on `ajaxComplete`. But that's a generalization, I'm not sure what you are doing with your server-side check.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.ajax` `success`:

**From [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
$("a.button").click(function() {
    var old_text = $(this).text();
    var button = $(this);
    $(this).text('Processing...');
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable to button to make sure it cannot be clicked
    data = ...;
    url = ...;
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        // after request has finished, re-enable the link
        $(button).removeAttr('disabled');
        $(button).text(old_text);
    });
});
```

Next thing, you should do something similar for catching errors (re-enable the button).

Answer (score 0):

It always depends the way you've built your site, but in my opinion the active state should only be triggered at the instant you click.

So that should be: onmousedown you add your class and onmouseup you remove it.

The Ajax call could trigger a different function maybe showing a loading dialog/spinner.

There are several ways of building it: individually on each element as you did, or through a general styling function. Same for Ajax with the ajaxStart ajaxComplete functions as Jasper said.

Personally I'm using Ajax intensively, always changing the DOM dynamically, so I use livequery to setup style changing with events automatically when elements with given class(es) appear in the DOM, and I use ajaxStart and ajaxComplete for displaying a loading dialog.